# JavaScript websocket.emit TypeError: socket.emit is not a function

Tags: javascript, websocket

I would like to emit special event from client side to server.
I created a code like this :

```
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9090');

let set_nickname = message => {
    socket.emit ("type-event",message)
}
```

It throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: socket.emit is not a function
```

I couldn't find a solution due to this problem (I'm not sure if emit is even implemented in websocket, I couldn't find a method in a specification, but webstorm suggests that I could use this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.emit()` is a part of [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/docs/v3/emitting-events/#Basic-emit) but you are using [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) API in a browser that uses [`.send()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/send) to emit data to server.

```
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9090');

socket.send("Hello server!");
```

Comment: So it's not possible to send a special type event different than 'message' with this object ?

Comment: @YoungUser yes so you'll have to implement your own logic for handling different event. maybe like prefixing the message with event name `event:message` and then check for event name on server